# How to make an integer long in Java?

Tags: java

So this is my code in the app called BlueJ as I am very new to Java:

Edit: I removed the rest of the code and just want to know how to use a long integer instead of a String. I have heard of something called 'long', just don't know how to use it if someone could help me on it.

```
    /**Mobile phone class that:
 * allows calling credit to be applied that is more than 0
 * shows remaining calling credit
 * allows a phone number to be added
 * shows duration of phone call 
 */
public class Mobile extends Gadget
{
    public int credit;
    public String phonenumber;
    public int duration;

    /**
    * Constructor for objects of class Mobile.
    */
    public Mobile(double ThePrice, int TheWeight, String TheModel, String TheSize) 
    {
        // initialise instance variables
        super(ThePrice, TheWeight, TheModel, TheSize);
    }
        /**
        * Insert the phone number
        */
        public void insertNumber(String number)
        {
            System.out.println("Phone number inserted!");
            phonenumber = phonenumber + number;
        }
```

For some reason, I still get an error saying 'Integer too large' when I made my phone number a String? How comes it is still being read as an integer?

Does anyone know a way around this so it can fit a phone number in that is long?

I used a string and get null(number).

Comment: Because you write `12345` instead of `"12345"` into the input popup (missing quotes for the number)?

Comment: reduce the code to the minimal possible snippet... tell us what method is giving the problem and  input/output

Comment: @Tom That was correct, how stupid of me. But is there a way to allow it without quotations? Like a long integer?

Comment: You can, but you shouldn't. Phone numbers often start with either `0` or `+` and `long` (and `int`) trim trailing zeros and don't support country codes. But you can do that if you like to test it, just replace the type of your phone number from `String` to `long`. But mind that `long` also has a [max value](https://garygregory.wordpress.com/2011/02/02/what-are-javas-min-and-max-values/). And mind that you might need to append an `l` or `L` to the number to "mark" it as a "long" instead of "int".

Comment: @Tom It still says it's too large? I did an 11 digit number.

Comment: Have you added `L` or `l` (e.g. "12345678912345L")? That's necessary here.

Comment: @Tom It says the same thing saying it's too large for some reason.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You can improve your question. Please read [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). When your code shows your precise problem with nothing extra, you are showing respect to those who volunteer to help you. In your case you removed to much. We don't know what  ``phonenumber`` is? Member variable? What is its type? Additionally your output isn't adding anything. Good luck.

Comment: @zhon I have edited it now

Comment: phone numbers, in practice, aren't really numbers at all as much as they're a unique addressing. That being said, an `int` can only be so large (roughly -2^32 to 2^32, but this isn't the actual min/max). This is due to how numbers are stored internally. You would use `Long#parseLong` to parse a larger number to a `long` datatype, but even then that may be too big, in which case you'd need to use `BigInteger`. Hence, it's usually best to keep them as strings.

Comment: @Dragon123, your comments can also be removed. There is much more to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to support North American phone numbers only, they are 10 digits long and fit within a Java long. However international phone numbers are more complicated, as hinted to above, and you would be well advised to use a string.

Comment: I do try a String, but it says 'null' infront of it.

Comment: What is phonenumber initialized with?

Comment: I initialised it with a String if I kept it as String, then long when I used Long. String says 'null<number>'. Long just says it's too long even if I enter L or l at the end of the input.

Comment: If it says null you must have initialized it as null.

Comment: I didn't do that, it just seems to say null before it.

Comment: Declaring a variable and initializing it are two different things. A string is an Object, so if you do not set a value to it (as a field), it will automatically set to `null`. Set it to the empty string: `String val = "";`.

Comment: @Rogue Thank you very much, it worked. I didn't know it was so simple. Excuse me, I am very new to this and missing out very easy, noticeable things.

Comment: @Dragon123 You can do what Rogue suggested, but the much cleaner way would be to remove `phonenumber = phonenumber + number;` and to replace it with `phonenumber = number;`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `phonenumber` string must be initialized. This could be done int the constructor or done via lazy evaluation.